# How to register with sinch for VoIP in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I am stuck in a place where i need to declare the following code of line in swift -

how to declare id client;

I am having hard time to find a code how to register with sinch in swift , so guys help me out

Comment: Can you add some code and what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I finally made it work :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,SINCallClientDelegate, SINCallDelegate , SINClientDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var callStatus: UILabel!

    let sinchClient : SINClient = Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey("093f31d0-858a-4947-b29e-38bd5b2300c5", applicationSecret: "iBS+k7WmnUOfKr5w1wureg==", environmentHost: "sandbox.sinch.com", userId: "John@transformative.in")


    var callClient : SINCallClient! ;
    var call : SINCall! ;
    var callClient : SINCallClient!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true)
        sinchClient.start()
        sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection()
        sinchClient.delegate = self
        callClient = sinchClient.callClient()

    }

    func clientDidStart(client: SINClient!) {
        print("Clien started")
    }

    func clientDidFail(client: SINClient!, error: NSError!) {

    }

    func clientDidStop(client: SINClient!) {

    }

    func client(client: SINClient!, logMessage message: String!, area: String!, severity: SINLogSeverity, timestamp: NSDate!) {

    }

    func callDidProgress(call: SINCall!) {

    }

    func callDidEstablish(call: SINCall!) {
        callStatus.text = "Call Connected"
    }

    func callDidEnd(call: SINCall!) {

    }

    func client(client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {
        call.delegate = self;
        call.answer()

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func callMike(sender: AnyObject) {

        let call : SINCall = callClient.callUserWithId("NewMan@transformative.in")
        call.delegate = self

    }

}
```

Comment: I've installed `Sinch` using `pod 'SinchRTC'` but unfortunately when I try to `import Sinch`  *I get no such module `Sinch`* .
Any help about installation

Comment: @Chlebta i did not use pod for installation , i just added the sinch framework mannually , but check your bridging header , have you imported it there

Comment: Yes, you got I've to sinch to the bridging-Header.h

Comment: hey mandeep I'm facing some issues and not getting help elseWhere, I followed this tutorial https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-simple-voice-app-tutorial/ , did exactly everything same, but no success by the i tried your code I'd a doubt why have you given static names ? I'm exactly taking the names from textfield as per the tutorial. Your code seems to be working with static names but mine isn't..